# Python make 5 row table with 5 columns a one row table with 11 rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 5 rows and 5 columns that I would like to make a new dataframe with 1 row.
I have tried working with pivots but I do not need the agg and I dont know what to try next.

I used Scott Boston's answer from this link to get this done.
[How to combine multiple rows into a single row with python pandas based on the values of multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51901068/how-to-combine-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-with-python-pandas-based-on-the-v)

**Starting table**

| month | ID | state | sales | customers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1234 | MN | 44 | 23 |
| 1 | 1234 | MN | 45 | 25 |
| 2 | 1234 | MN | 51 | 27 |
| 3 | 1234 | MN | 47 | 29 |
| 4 | 1234 | MN | 44 | 29 |
| 0 | 5555 | NY | 441 | 231 |
| 1 | 5555 | NY | 451 | 251 |
| 2 | 5555 | NY | 511 | 271 |
| 3 | 5555 | NY | 471 | 291 |
| 4 | 5555 | NY | 441 | 291 |

```
data = [['0', '1234','MN',44,23],['1', '1234','MN',45,25],['2', '1234','MN',51,27],['3', '1234','MN',47,29],['4', '1234','MN',44,29],['0', '5555','NY',441,231],['1', '5555','NY',451,251],['2', '5555','NY',511,27],['3', '5555','NY',471,291],['4', '5555','NY',441,291],]

t1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['month', 'ID', 'state', 'sales', 'customers'])
```

**Ideal Final table**

| ID | state | sales_0 | customer_0 | sales_1 | customer_1 | sales_2 | customer_2 | sales_3 | customer_3 | sales_4 | customer_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | MN | 44 | 23 | 45 | 25 | 51 | 27 | 47 | 29 | 44 | 29 |
| 5555 | NY | 441 | 231 | 451 | 251 | 511 | 271 | 471 | 291 | 441 | 291 |

I would need this to work for millions of IDs and months up to 50

Comment: You can use`df.pivot_table( index = ['month','ID'], columns=['state'], aggfunc='first').reset_index()`.

Comment: The output of this is still a long table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.chain` module to flatten your data input then you can drop the columns you don't need.

Here is an example:

```
from itertools import chain
import pandas as pd


data = [
  ['0', '1234','MN',44,23],
  ['1', '1234','MN',45,25],
  ['2', '1234','MN',51,27],
  ['3', '1234','MN',47,29],
  ['4', '1234','MN',44,29]
]
columns = ['month', 'ID', 'state', 'sales', 'customer']

flattened = chain.from_iterable(data)
cols = columns + [
  f"{j}_{k}" for k in range(len(columns) -1) for j in columns
]
df = pd.DataFrame([list(flattened)], columns=cols)

columns_to_drop = ['month'] + [
  f"{j}_{k}" for k in range(len(columns) - 1) for j in ['ID', 'month']
]
df.drop(columns=columns_to_drop, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     ID state  sales  customer state_0  sales_0  customer_0 state_1  sales_1  customer_1 state_2  sales_2  customer_2 state_3  sales_3  customer_3
0  1234    MN     44        23      MN       45          25      MN       51          27      MN       47          29      MN       44          29
```

Comment: This is really cool but if there is a 5 million IDs and 50 months for each the data list is going to be huge.

Comment: @Jeffkrop you're reading your data from a file or do you generate it under your process ?

Comment: Reading it from a text file output of a SQL query

Comment: Then you need to consider using `dask`

Comment: So this works with one ID and if the months always start at zero but testing it with more than one ID and it is looking for more columns not added the new ID to the next row.

Comment: @Jeffkrop This is another question for another answer.