# Combine top n-th rows of a group into a single row of list with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

Fairly new to Python and Pandas here.

I am trying to combine the top nth rows based on the values in a separate column into a single row with Pandas.

Using a hypothetical example, let's say I have the following table that is already sorted desc by the 'amount' column:

| store_id | item | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | shirt | 5 |
| 00001 | sock | 3 |
| 00001 | pants | 1 |
| 00002 | sock | 4 |
| 00002 | pants | 2 |
| 00002 | shirt | 1 |

I would like to generate a table that groups by the store_id, with each row being a list of the top n items based on the value of the 'amount' column. So if I wanted to see the top 2 items by store_id, the table would look like this:

| store_id | item |
| --- | --- |
| 00001 | ['shirt', 'sock'] |
| 00002 | ['sock', 'pants'] |

I tried following along with the suggestion here: [How to combine multiple rows into a single row with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36392735/how-to-combine-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-with-pandas) , however I keep running into a "'GroupedData' object is not subscriptable" error.

Would greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to solve this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it that you just want to get n top elements from each group or n largest elements from each group? If it is former then you use `df.groupby(...).first(2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your table is already sorted desc by the `amount` column, you can get the top n-th rows for each group by [`GroupBy.head(n)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html).  To further group `item` column of these top n-th rows into list, you can further use [`GroupBy.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.aggregate.html), as follows:

```
n = 2      # define n

(df.groupby('store_id').head(n)
   .groupby('store_id')['item'].agg(list)
).reset_index()
```

**Result:**

```
   store_id           item
0         1  [shirt, sock]
1         2  [sock, pants]
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @moses  Pleased to help!   :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(df.sort_values('amount',ascending=False)
 .groupby('store_id')
 .agg({'item':lambda x: x.iloc[0:2].tolist()}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
output = df.groupby("store_id") \
           .apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2, "amount")["item"].tolist()) \
           .rename(index="item")

>>> output
store_id
00001    [shirt, sock]
00002    [sock, pants]
Name: item, dtype: object
```