# Combine two row datas into one based on Condition using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have below dilemma and cannot find any answer online.

I have data in separate rows:

```
Payment 
Chq 102100
Payment Bank
Payment
Chq 123000
```

And I need help to combine rows with chq number to its above row like below:

```
Payment Chq 102100
Payment Bank
Payment Chq 123000
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your data is ambiguous, please provide it as dataframe constructor or dictionary

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36392735/how-to-combine-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-with-pandas) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom group to `groupby` like below:

```
# Input data
>>> df

              0
0      Payment 
1    Chq 102100
2  Payment Bank
3       Payment
4    Chq 123000

# Output result
>>> df[0].str.strip() \
         .groupby(df[0].str.contains('^Payment').cumsum()) \
         .agg(' '.join).to_frame()

                    0
0                    
1  Payment Chq 102100
2        Payment Bank
3  Payment Chq 123000
```