# Group by Pandas and combine multipe strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe currently which resembles this

```
Source | Destination | Type
A | B | Insert
A | B | Delete
B | C | Insert
```

What I want to achieve is something like this

```
Source | Destination | Type
A | B | Insert, Delete
B | C | Insert
```

I tried using group by Source and Destination but Im a little unsure how do I append to the type. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine multiple rows into a single row with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36392735/how-to-combine-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-with-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

Check Below Code:

```
df.groupby(['Source','Destination']).agg({'Type':'unique'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out something

```
df = df.groupby(['Source','Destination'])['Type'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x)).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a string separated by ", ":

```py
df.groupby(['Source', 'Destination']).agg(', '.join).reset_index()
```

Make a list:

```py
df.groupby(['Source','Destination']).agg(list).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Joining by , and building a string works but it is not very convenient if you later want to perform other operations with this column value. (such as iterating over the elements.)

This creates a set of values.

column_map: Dict[str,Any] = {}
column_map["Type"] = lambda x: set(x)

df.groupby(["Source", "Destination"]).agg(column_map)

```
Source | Destination | Type
A | B | {Insert Delete}
B | C | {Insert}
```

if you instead want to get a list and dont want eliminate duplicates. Just replace `set(x)` with `list(x)`